# String variable prefixed with undefined in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down on which i use .Change() to trigger a function. Function basically  get certain data using `getJSON` and based on those value in have to create string of array for mp3 file.

Below code is generating string but always prefix `undefined` to string.

In code you will notice `setTimeout` which is just to provide certain delay till data received. In below example i am using static value and it still prefix `undefined`. not sure why may be i have defined variable in wrong manner.

Complete example [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nicutokago/edit?html,output)

```
$('.customSurah').change(function(){
    //surahNo = $('#surah option:selected').val();

    setTimeout(function(){ 
    //countSpan = $('#surah-wrapper').children().length;
    surahNo = 1;
    countSpan = 7;
    var i=0;
         for (i = 0; i <= countSpan; i++) {
            strCat += surahNo+"/"+i+".mp3,";
            console.log(strCat);
        }
    }, 3000);

 });
```

**OUTPUT**

```
undefined114/0.mp3,
undefined114/0.mp3,114/1.mp3,
undefined114/0.mp3,114/1.mp3,114/2.mp3,
undefined114/0.mp3,114/1.mp3,114/2.mp3,114/3.mp3,
undefined114/0.mp3,114/1.mp3,114/2.mp3,114/3.mp3,114/4.mp3,
undefined114/0.mp3,114/1.mp3,114/2.mp3,114/3.mp3,114/4.mp3,114/5.mp3,
undefined114/0.mp3,114/1.mp3,114/2.mp3,114/3.mp3,114/4.mp3,114/5.mp3,114/6.mp3,
```

Comment: where is `strCat` defined? declare it with initial value as blank string and it should work fine

Comment: It is defined out side for loop here is the complete example http://jsbin.com/nicutokago/edit?html,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable `strCat` that is not initialized, and then you append a value to it in this line:

```
strCat += surahNo+"/"+i+".mp3,";
```

Since `strCat` is not initialized in first round of loop, you get `undefined` prepended to your string.

To fix this, you need to initialize the variable to empty value first:

```
var strCat = '';   // <- initialize your variable to empty value
surahNo = 1;
countSpan = 7;
```

Comment: some one is just marking us with downvote and not mentioning any reason. Could the downvote user justify downvote

Comment: You got it right, I am not a JavaScript guy use it very rarely.. Did teh basic mistake.

Comment: I think SO user mentioned in this comment that he has defined strCat  outside the loop

Comment: @user2181397 no so user said he declared it outside

Comment: @FastSnail can you please verify his comment

Comment: @user2181397 defining  and initializing is different.

Answer (score 3):

The outcome is perfectly valid as per javascript is concerned.

Why?

I guess you probably know if you declare any variable in javascript and you don't assign its default value then automatically `undefined` is assigned. So, that is a valid. What happens when you do that:

```js
var somevar; // non assigned default value set to -> undefined
console.log(somevar); // logs undefined
```

But,
In your case you have to give it a default value like  a blank string `var strCat "";`. So, now when you do this:

```js
var somevar = ""; // assigned default value to set to -> ""
console.log(somevar); // logs ""
```

---

So, the solution to your issue is, you have to **initialize/assign** a default value to your variable. like:

```
var strCat = "";
```